# Эпитафия на камне

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

> Ты навсегда для нас пример для подражания.
>   Мы все живём, сверяясь по тебе...

Хотелось бы знать правильность написания и расстановки пунктуации. После изготовления исправлять на камне сложно.

Comment: Вера, дорогая, не передёргивайте, я сказала "по элементарным вопросам".Ответили, напомнили правило - и всё, а как каждый из нас его понимает и чего ещё напридумает к уже всем грамотным людям известному (а мы должны предполагать, что на этом форуме грамотные люди, "школоту"сразу видно, вот их нужно учить),я думаю, лишнее.Вот когда что-то спорное - ДА. Если кто-то ответил верно, я стараюсь не отвечать, просто голосую, что согласна, ну, может, добавлю в комментарии. А Вы всегда что-то выискиваете, поучаете всех.Зачем?

Answer (score 1):

Ты навсегда для нас пример для подражания. Мы все живём, сверяясь по тебе...

Ошибок нет. Вы в чём сомневаетесь? Хотите поставить тире: Ты навсегда для нас - пример для подражания? Нет, тире не нужно, потому что сост. именное сказуемое относится к личному местоимению (Я учитель) и между ними есть наречие. Если будет тире, оно будет авторское для пафоса. Он Вам нужен? Восклицательный знак - излишняя патетика, зачем?

Comment: Спасибо огромное.

Answer (score 0):

"Ты навсегда для нас пример для подражания".

Тире между подлежащим и составным именным сказуемым не ставится, но дело здесь не в пафосе, а в том, что дополнение  "для нас" относится и к сказуемому, и к подлежащему, а при постановке тире оно будет относиться к одному главному члену.

Comment: Одним из вариантов было тире после слова "Ты". Спасибо огромное за оперативность и за исчерпывающие ответы.

Comment: Не вижу в этом смысла, и при тире, и без него одинаково отношение дополнения к сказуемому, потому что дополнение - объект действия: Пример для кого? - для нас, а не ты для кого? - для нас. И вообще, человеку надо знать, есть ли здесь ошибка, а до наших научных прений - словоблудий ему дела нет.

Comment: Мы же не только для конкретных людей отвечаем, но и истину пытаемся найти. Я приведу два примера с разным оформлением: Стихи для вас одна забава. Минута с ней – небесный рай. В первом случае дополнение (стихи для вас, забава для вас), во втором случае - несогласованное определение, отнесенное к подлежащему.

Comment: Во-первых,Я ВСЕГДА отвечаю конкретному человеку на конкретный вопрос, он ведь ждёт ответа, пустые разглагольствования вокруг да около его не интересуют. Иначе зачем этот сайт? Я здесь, чтобы помочь людям разрешить сомнения, а не показать свою образованность.Видимо, поэтому у нас с Вами сразу возникло непонимание - и когда Вы были Софией, и когда Верой(ничего личного, я вижу, что Вы грамотный человек, но иной раз своей убеждённостью, что только Вы правы, а остальные ошибаются и знают меньше Вас, ставите  в тупик).

Comment: Во-вторых,в предложении "Стихи для вас одна забава" нет тире, потому что нет паузы, её заполнило дополнение(а оно всегда относится ко всей грамматической основе), а в НАШЕМ случае между подлежащим и сказуемым есть и наречие-обстоятельство, и дополнение, поэтому паузы нет. Правило: 
Если между подлежащим и именной частью сказуемого, выраженными сущ. в И.п., находятся  служебные или вводные слова,  а также дополнение или обстоятельство, отнесенное ко всему предложению,   то пауза не делается и тире не ставится. Я это и сказала.А главное - что тире не ставится, если подлеж.- личное мест. ТЫ.

Comment: И вообще, не хочу никаких дискуссий по элементарным вопросам. О чём спорить-то? Всё по правилам, только нужно их напомнить тем, кто забыл.

Comment: Ну да,  форум, как и парламент, - не место для дискуссий, о чем спорить-то? На том и остановимся.